# Implicit type parameters in Haskell class definition?

Tags: haskell, type-inference, typeclass

It normally seems the following is illegal:

```
class Foo a where
    foo :: a -> b -> a
```

Which makes sense; how do we know what `b` is?

However, if we look at Functor's definition:

```
class Functor f where
    fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

we see `a` and `b` showing up even though we only specify `f` as a type variable. I'm guessing this is allowed because the compiler sees e.g. `f a` and can figure out that `f` itself must take an `a`, so it's safe to use that `a` elsewhere in our Functor definition. Am I correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's look at each line separately.

```
class Functor f where
```

This declares a single-parameter type class called `Functor`; the type which satisfies it will be called `f`.

```
  fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

Like any function definition, all the free type variables are implicitly `forall`ed—they can be replaced with anything.  However, thanks to the first line, `f` is in scope.  Thus, `fmap` has the type signature `fmap :: forall a b. Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`.  In other words, every functor needs to have a definition of `fmap` which can work for *any* `a` and `b`, and `f` must have **kind** (the type of a type) `* -> *`; that is, it must be a type which takes another type, such as `[]` or `Maybe` or `IO`.

What you said, then, is incorrect; the `a` isn't special, and if we had another function in `Functor`, it wouldn't see the same `a` or `b`.  However, the compiler *does* use the `f a` bit to figure out what the kind of `f` must be.  Additionally, your `Foo` class is perfectly legal; I could specify an instance as follows

```
instance Foo (a -> b) where
  foo f _ = f
```

This satisfies `foo :: a -> b -> a` for *any* `b`; note that the `b` in `Foo (a -> b)` is different.  Admittedly, it's not a very interesting instance, but it's perfectly legal.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't need to "know". It just needs to typecheck (i.e. not fail to typecheck). `b` can be anything; and the function `foo` must be able to take any type as second parameter.

Consider the `const` function from Prelude:

```
const            :: a -> b -> a
const x _        =  x
```

How does it "know" what `b` (or `a`, for that matter) is?